# How do I convert a numpy array into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to have the 3 columns of a numpy array

```
px[:,:,0]
px[:,:,1]
px[:,:,0]
```

into a pandas Dataframe.

Should I use?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(px, columns=['R', 'G', 'B'])
```

Thank you

Hugo

Comment: you have to pass DataFrame with 2D input, not a 3D array

Comment: May I slice through columns?
df = pd.DataFrame((px[:,:,0],px[:,:,1],px[:,:,2]), columns=['R', 'G', 'B'])

Comment: np, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Could you post the content of `px`?

Comment: [[[ 16  47   3]
  [ 14  45   1]
  [  6  39   0]
  ..., 
  [ 40  71  39]
  [ 42  73  41]
  [ 46  77  45]]

 [[  8  41   0]
  [  2  35   0]
  [ 23  56  11]
  ..., 
  [ 35  69  32]
  [ 38  72  37]
  [ 41  75  40]]

 [[  6  39   0]
  [ 24  60  14]
  [ 31  67  21]

Comment: I need to have the R,G,B values of each pixel in a diferent column of the Dataframe

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to reshape your array first, try this:

```
px2 = px.reshape((-1,3))
df = pd.DataFrame({'R':px2[:,0],'G':px2[:,1],'B':px2[:,2]})
```